# Next state (*) in Haskell union types

Tags: haskell, f#

How can I translate this from F# to Haskell?

```
type Exit =
    | PassableExit of string * destination: RoomId
    | LockedExit of string * key: Item * next: Exit 
    | NoExit of string option
```

Complete code:
https://github.com/thedevaspect/aspect-fsharp/blob/master/Game.fs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a translation would be

```hs
data Exit
   = PassableExit String RoomId
   | LockedExit String Item Exit
   | NoExit (Maybe String)
```

if you want the labels/accessors as well:

```hs
data Exit
   = PassableExit { info :: String, destination :: RoomId }
   | LockedExit { info :: String, key :: Item, next :: Exit }
   | NoExit { infoOption :: Maybe String }
```

of course F# uses Tuples so this would be more direct (although not *idiomatic*):

```hs
data Exit
   = PassableExit (String, RoomId)
   | LockedExit (String, Item, Exit)
   | NoExit (Maybe String)
```

Comment: Hmm not idiomatic, and introduces an extra layer of constructor to unwrap. Would using F# Tuples also have an extra layer to unwrap? Or does F# not see it as a tuple `(,)` constructor nested inside the `PassableExit` constructor?

Comment: AFAIK F#'s version is translated into a .NET class with the labels being turned into fields/properties. I'd not worry about performance here too much though

Comment: I heard it would make working with JSON streams an issue.

Comment: @AntC, in OCaml, `Fish of scales * gills` has the fields directly in the `Fish` constructor, whereas `Rodent of (teeth * fur)` would contain a tuple. I imagine F# is similar.

Comment: @dfeuer yes it is